# Google My Business API return 429 code all time

Tags: google-my-business-api

> { "error": { "code": 429, "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric
> 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service
> 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:xxx'.", "errors": [ { "message": "Quota
> exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute'
> of service 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:xxx'.", "domain": "global", "reason":
> "rateLimitExceeded" } ], "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" } }

Why do I receive such a message immediately after logging in?
I haven't had time to use api yet

Comment: did you find solution? as i faced this error now i checked console and there is 0 request limit for each minute in api quotas. i didn't get how to workaround this

Comment: apparently you need to send a separate request for access to the api https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XTQc-QEjsE7YrgstyJxbFDnwmhUhBFFvpNJBw3VzuuE/viewform

Comment: Any updates? Facing same @Dry7 i have applied for the access to API and got approved still facing this issue

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Does the google team increase your quotas after you filled the form? Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 5):

I guess you already applied for accesss to GMB API and GMB Account Management API.
You usually get approved for both in less than 2 weeks, but, here comes the answer to your question, now you also need to request an increase for the GMB Account Management API Quota, as this API get approved with a 0 quota.
You can request this from a couple different places. I think I requested mine from the project Quota section in console.cloud.google.com.
You should get your new quota in 1-2 weeks.

It is clear they should update reference docs more in detail.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Found the form here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdoCw8P5JJsJ-taCH2i8w8B69sGsZfoRhacQOe7FTWArWZ-SQ/viewform?fbzx=2253286086101214471

Comment: Hi, same problem here. I filled the form 2 times, without any reply from the Google team. The form is still valid? Is there a way to contact someone? It's a blocking point to use the API.

Comment: I am also facing the issue regarding Google My Business api quota. I submitted the form but did not get any reply after almost 3 weeks.

Comment: thanks this helps alot https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdoCw8P5JJsJ-taCH2i8w8B69sGsZfoRhacQOe7FTWArWZ-SQ/viewform

Comment: this has never been an issue for me and now all of a sudden i get both cors and 429 errors

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found an answer! The Google console has a major ux **BUG** in it. When you don't use the api for a while, it Google will disable the Business API (or it gets disabled after the API update).

HOWEVER, the Google console will still show that your My Business API access is enabled! While in reality it's not! And the button to the google form requesting the access is gone, so you can pull your hairs out, because the other My Business related apis will show you 0 quota, even though the main My Business API will show you non-zero quota and that it's enabled while it's not.

You have to [re-request your google my business api here](https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfC_FKSWzbSae_5rOpgwFeIUzXUF1JCQnlsZM_gC1I2UHjA3w/viewform) again, even if it shows you that you already have it enabled.

It took us weeks to realize that Google has a bug on their side (and they haven't even bothered to fix it or admit that they have a bug in their panel, they just sid "access is not enabled" when contacting them).

Developing with Google has always been and still is a true hell on earth, very comparable to Facebook developer experience.

Comment: Oh whell, now to find out why i get CORS errors on one business endpoint and not on another, while i use the same OAuth client ...