# New My Business Account Management API quotas and access

Tags: google-my-business-api

I currently us the Google My Business API with no problems (july 2021).

But Google is migrated this API to several new API. The first one is My Business Account Management API.

In the cloud console, I have activated this API in the project. It's activated, but the request quotas is 0. So, it's unusable.

I found this question which seems to be the same problem, but it didn't work for the moment: [Google My Business API return 429 code all time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834591/google-my-business-api-return-429-code-all-time)

I filled the form, but no reply.

2 questions:

- do I need to do something else to have the access granted to the new API or just activate it in the console project is enough ?
- Is the form the right way to ask to increase quotas ?

Thanks a lot for your reply.

[image]