# 429 error while using 0auth 2.0 playground

Tags: oauth2-playground

I am having a problem retrieving the accounts in 0auth 2.0 playground. After following the steps in the Google Business API's basic setup, 0auth 2.0 playground returns a 429 response code. So far, I have double checked that the google my business api is enabled, and then tried following the steps in the Google Profile API's basic setup again. I have requested a higher quota, but what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a duplicate of [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834591/google-my-business-api-return-429-code-all-time). On that thread it looks like the summary of steps to resolve are:

- [Request access to the API steps](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access)

  - [Apply for access to the API](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfC_FKSWzbSae_5rOpgwFeIUzXUF1JCQnlsZM_gC1I2UHjA3w/viewform)
- [Apply for a higher than 0 quota](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdoCw8P5JJsJ-taCH2i8w8B69sGsZfoRhacQOe7FTWArWZ-SQ/viewform) or via the project Quota section in console.cloud.google.com

Comment: Hey @Thomas thank you! I have applied for a higher than 0 quota, but would you happen to know if this is the usual? It seems that it would make sense that the API should come with a quota limit for testing in 0auth, but it doesn't

Comment: I don't know if this is typical. I found this [limits doc](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/limits?hl=en#all-other-calls) that seems to indicate that it should be over 0? perhaps you didn't have a billing account attached to the project and that is the cause, not sure though. I suspect the standard quota request form should provide above 0 quota once approved.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I don't have a billing account associated with the project. However, I've been granted a higher quota limit, but I am still getting a 429 error code

Comment: Are you following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request) in order to make the request? perhaps try adding the `X-GOOG-API-FORMAT-VERSION: 2` request header to see if it gives you a better error message instead of just the 429 error code?